# Play a recorded video from Ustream

Tags: ios

I've seen the other day there's one way to play embed videos from Ustream on iOS, but I'm looking a way to play the recorded videos, like this, http://www.ustream.tv/recorded/15480382 , anybody knows how?

Thanks in advance